# Use Nuget for shared Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget

I'm starting a new application that will share the same navigation bar (content at least) with other apps down the road.  These will all be hosted on the same domain, but potentially different servers.

I know Nuget can be used to share libraries, but what's the potential use for it in sharing shared views, like a _SharedHeader, _Master pages.  Each app would have to pull down the new nuget package and be redeployed to see a change in the navigation bar for example, but this code change is in one place versus in each app updating the _SharedHeader.

Are there other options that would be better? I'm not sure how sites in ISS inherit shared views, I've run into them sharing web.configs in virtual directories.

Is using one nuget package for shared views possible and a good idea, what are other possible reprocussions?  My knowledge of nuget, mvc, and the relating subject matter is very rudimentary, but this seems like a good idea to manage code.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You can use NuGet packages to install pre defined shared views ( that would be used by multiple projects). Take a look @ http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/configuration-file-and-source-code-transformations for more details.

Answer (score 1):

In order to share views from a class library, you must compile them. There's an addon for this purpose called [RazorGenerator](http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/). How to use RazorGenerator is beyond the scope of what I can provide in an answer, but the link above and a little research online should give you all you need to set it up.

Once you've got your views in a class library, creating a nuget package out of it works the same as anything else. So again, let Google guide the way.

Comment: Hi, I had created a NuGet package that will bind a tree. I did it by using normal views which will automatically be added to the project when installing the package. Now I want to replace the view with Precompiled View. After adding precompiled view it is not working. The dll is present in the installed project but the compiler can't find the view. Is there any alterative for this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ability of a NuGet package to contain content, not just libraries to achieve this.  When the NuGet package is installed, it would then copy the shared views into your project.  This will give you the benefit of being able to tweak these shared views should your project require it.

Here is the [Nuspec Reference](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuspec-reference).  I can't link directly to it, but scroll down to **File Element Examples**, then **Content Files**